# cache large data in session on memcache server

Tags: php, session, memcached

I had set two memcached server for my php server to cache some database data in session.

When I select more than 20000 records with 20 columns data and cache into php session, it would take more than 1 second to do session_start();

Why? And how can I speed up it?

Comment: Why are you caching so much data in one big chunk (table)? More info about how you decide what to cache and how you use the cached data would be helpful.

Comment: my website using datatable's serverside to show user data, if no using cache, it will hit database every times when client change page, so i want to cache all user data in to session, and take it form session rather than database.

Comment: *Datatable's serverside will get current page's data only, so it will request php when client change page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it takes a long time to start a session because memcache and PHP have to unserialize hundreds of thousands of table cells for every request. I bet it takes longer than if you just used a database.

Your implementation is really inefficient: if a single user needs access to her session, you load data about all users. To speed things up significantly, change how you store values in the cache; store only the current user's data, not the whole table!

Instead of building the cache this way:

```
$SESSION['data'] = [
    'ID_1'=>['name'=>'jane', 'email'=>'...'],
    'ID_2'=>['name'=>'john', 'email'=>'...'],
    ... //20,000 rows
];
```

Just do this:

```
$SESSION['data'] = [
    'ID_1'=>['name'=>'jane', 'email'=>'...']//a single row
];
```

Now when you call `session_start()` only the current users' row is loaded, not the whole table.

**Addendum**

My response was addressing an individual user browsing his pages. In the case of an admin who requires the script to filter through all records, I would just access the database with `SELECT` statements. Make sure to select only the columns and the rows needed. It will probably be faster than loading the whole table from the cache.

Anyway, you can test it very quickly by commenting out `session_start()` and all `$_SESSION` references, and querying the database for the info you need.

Comment: But if I am admin, I need to show all user data in to list(datatable list 10 users per page, datatable will request php to get 10 records when admin change page), I must load all data and take part of data from session. Also, in order to decrease hit database, I want to cache all users data in session. 
When I need first 10 records, I take $_SESSION['data][0] to $_SESSION['data][9].
When I need 1001 to 1010 records, I take $_SESSION['data'][1000] to $_SESSION['data'][1009]
If I want to decrease hit database times, I must save all data in session, but it will slow down.
So, is my idea wrong?

Comment: If no, is large data slow down session_start();? 
If yes, Must I use other method to do this?

Comment: Using the DB might be faster. I added to my answer.